# weighted trie for autosuggest feature

Tags: data-structures, trie

I have a trie (suffix tree) which I am using for an auto-suggest feature in my website.

Now I want to show the most popular (most highly-weighted) text above text with a lower weight. How can I change my trie so that suggestions come out in weighted order.

Or should I just sort by weight in memory?

Answer (score 4):

You could add a `count` or `weight` property at each node and update it as you build the trie using your words. Each character will have an initial weight of `0`, but if a character  is the terminal character of a word, then it will have an initial weight of `1`. As you keep adding words, you can adjust the weights on terminal characters.

So, for example, you could have:

```
t:0
|  
o:1
|
w:3---e:0
|  \    \
n:2 a:0  l:4
     \
      r:0
       \
        d:2
```

For the strings `to` (appearing once), `tow` (appearing thrice), `towel` (appearing four times), `town` (appearing twice), and `toward` (also appearing twice).

Then if you had the prefix `tow`, you can look at non-zero weighted strings such as `tow:3`, `towel:4`, `town:2`, and `toward:2`.

After that, you can sort based on weight.

I haven't tried out this implementation in practice; this is just an idea.